# Confirm dialog is not opening react-admin

Tags: react-admin, confirm

I am trying to open a confirmation dialog when the button is clicked with React Admin. The button click name is 'handleSendItemsToUpdate'.

However the dialog is not opening.

Please find the code below:

```
  const notify = useNotify();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleDialogClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const handleSendItemsToUpdate = (props) => {

    const handleConfirm = () => {
        notify('Stuff is done.');
        setOpen(false);
    };

    setOpen(true);


    return (

        <Fragment>
            <SaveButton {...props} />
            <Confirm
                isOpen={open}
                title="Update View Count"
                content="Are you sure you want to reset the views for these items?"
                onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                onClose={handleDialogClose}
            />
        </Fragment>
    );
}

...
<Button className={classes.button} onClick={() => handleSendItemsToUpdate(props)}>Send Items To 
Update</Button>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Begum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Confirm dialog is returned in the `handleSendItemsToUpdate` function, which is not rendered in the component (used in the DOM), that's why it cannot be shown.

You can put the return in the function to the return of component, and of course, it is only shown when the open state is true.

You can check for my demo here: `https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-dewdney-6pil2?file=/src/App.js`

Comment: Thank you so much :) When I put the confirm in component return the diaolog is open !!

Comment: Hi Begum, a better way to place the confirm (or any type of modal) in React by putting it in the <App> component and managing its open state and content by using redux, so you can open and update the content in the modal anywhere in any component.
Hope that will help :D